# Issue on parsing Html with jsoup for java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse HTML using jsoup.

I used "try jsoup" to check if parsing of the html is correct.

screenshot of the results : [please open this link ^^](http://ppt.cc/qhEl)

My code is :

```
    URL url = new URL("http://tw.search.bid.yahoo.com/search/ac;_ylt=AtqkyTO06sgGHho20HzmPEX3_rF8?ei=UTF-8&p=%E8%A1%A3%E6%9C%8D");
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
        Elements descriptions = doc.select("div#srp_sl_result"+" div.att-item");

        for (Element element : descriptions) {  
            System.out.println(element.ownText());
            System.out.println("--------------");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

But the results are returning empty,
I am getting following output:

```
--------------

--------------

--------------
```

I am expecting output like:

```
女裝手套衣服＊艾爾莎＊暗釦長款披風式毛衣罩衫外套S~L【TAA1166】 出價 799 元 直購 799 元 運費80元 ｜    
30 次 ｜ 剩 16小時 60分 賣家：艾爾莎時尚精品 (評價 25229) 在新北市
☆意樂舖☆【塑鋼衣架】ABS強化多功能神奇魔術衣架(收納衣服.領帶.皮帶.肩帶) 出價 35 元 直購 35 元 運費
55元 ｜ 8 次 ｜ 1天 6小時 賣家：意樂舖(創意樂園小舖) (評價 14613) 在新北市
HappyLife【YK1324】韓國超人氣乾濕兩用衣架 防滑魔術衣架 止滑衣架 衣服衣櫃衣櫥收納 出價 25 元 直購 
25 元 運費70元 ｜ 16 次 ｜ 2天 3小時 賣家：HappyLife快樂生活網 (評價 14360) 在新北市
```

Here is some sample HTML from the search page:

```
 <div class="att-item item yui3-g " data-url="https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.intl=tw&amp;.pd=c%3D3Chd7Yq72e502eh4R99sgUvi5Q--&amp;.done=https%3A%2F%2Ftw.search.bid.yahoo.com%2Fsearch%2Fauction%2Fproduct%3Fei%3DUTF-8%26p%3D%25E8%25A1%25A3%25E6%259C%258D&amp;rr=2465463942"> 
    <div class="yui3-u"> 
        <div class="srp-pdimage"> 
            <a href="https://tw.page.bid.yahoo.com/tw/auction/e79010279;_ylt=ApstmFiftkQPQ2krNhqCT3xyFbN8;_ylv=3"> <img height="120" alt=" (DAJIN達錦衣服設計中心)棒壘球帽字凸繡200元，棒球帽，帽子，棒壘球服，棒球衣 " src="https://s.yimg.com/hg/ac/30/ea/e79010279-ac-4511xf9x0430x0600-s.jpg" /> </a> 
        </div> 
     </div> 
 </div>
```

What should I change in my code?
How to achieve my goal.

Please help me!

Comment: HELLO,I am trying to parse html is ：http://tw.search.bid.yahoo.com/search/ac;_ylt=AtqkyTO06sgGHho20HzmPEX3_rF8?ei=UTF-8&p=%E8%A1%A3%E6%9C%8D

Comment: And I use "try jsoup" is :http://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: "try jsoup" is  check to parse html is Correct.

Comment: seems to be working for me, do you have the latest version of jSoup?

Comment: HELLO,I use jsoup is jsoup-1.7.3.jar  http://jsoup.org/download
It for my study >///<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `text()` method, not `ownText()`, as the documentation states, it:

> Gets the combined text of this element and all its children.

Here is an updated example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL( "http://tw.search.bid.yahoo.com/search/"
            + "ac;_ylt=AtqkyTO06sgGHho20HzmPEX3_rF8?ei=UTF-8&p=%E8%A1%A3%E6%9C%8D");

    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
        Elements descriptions = doc.select("div#srp_sl_result div.att-item");

        for (Element element : descriptions) {
            System.out.println(element.text());
            System.out.println("--------------");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've visited the page you are trying to parse and in the browser console I've written:

```
$('div#srp_sl_result div.att-item')
```

The search returned a div:

```
<div class="att-item item yui3-u" data-url="https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.intl=tw&amp;.pd=c%3D3Chd7Yq72e502eh4R99sgUvi5Q--&amp;.done=https%3A%2F%2Ftw.search.bid.yahoo.com%2Fsearch%2Fauction%2Fproduct%3Fei%3DUTF-8%26p%3D%25E8%25A1%25A3%25E6%259C%258D&amp;rr=3456505015" id="yui_3_14_1_3_1394093660536_452">
        <div class="wrap" id="yui_3_14_1_3_1394093660536_451">
            <div class="srp-pdimage" id="yui_3_14_1_3_1394093660536_450">
                <a href="https://tw.page.bid.yahoo.com/tw/auction/f61398121;_ylt=Ali1FeHY3kStUUeBmGO4vupyFbN8;_ylv=3?u=Y2583393636" id="yui_3_14_1_3_1394093660536_456">
                    <img width="200" alt=" HappyLife【SP323】納川6+1家庭裝真空收納袋/真空袋/壓縮袋/棉被衣物衣服收納~附吸氣管 " src="https://s.yimg.com/hg/ac/b6/51/f61398121-ac-6849xf8x0600x0400-s.jpg" id="yui_3_14_1_3_1394093660536_455">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="srp-pdhead">
                <div class="srp-pdinfo">
                    <a class="srp-bid" href="https://tw.page.bid.yahoo.com/tw/show/bid_hist;_ylt=Ahu0X7QeYNL6gEwV.IhDhWlyFbN8;_ylv=3?aID=f61398121">6 次</a>
                    <span>出價</span>
                    <em>399</em>
                    <span>元</span>
                    <span class="sep">｜</span>
                </div>
                        <div class="srp-pdprice">
                    <span>直購</span>
                    <em>399</em>
                    <span>元</span>
                </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="srp-pdtitle">
                <a href="https://tw.page.bid.yahoo.com/tw/auction/f61398121;_ylt=AiNoFG2AOvisNBiTc.AyjgxyFbN8;_ylv=3?u=Y2583393636"> HappyLife【SP323】納川6+1家庭裝真空收納袋/真空袋/壓縮袋/棉被衣物衣服收納~附吸氣管 </a>
            </div>
            <div class="srp-pdftitle">
                <a href="https://tw.page.bid.yahoo.com/tw/auction/f61398121;_ylt=AiNoFG2AOvisNBiTc.AyjgxyFbN8;_ylv=3?u=Y2583393636"> HappyLife【SP323】納川6+1家庭裝真空收納袋/真空袋/壓縮袋/棉被衣物衣服收納~附吸氣管 </a>
            </div>
            <div class="srp-pdstore">
                                <a class="srp-ico" href="https://tw.help.yahoo.com/auct/policy/protection.html#reward" alt="享買賣家五萬保障"></a>
                                <a href="http://tw.user.bid.yahoo.com/tw/user/Y2583393636;_ylt=Akxsb34F0Y37vNFzvvX8aldyFbN8;_ylv=3">HappyLife快樂生活網</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So I don't understand why you have so many elements returned. In any case `element.ownText()` returns the text of that div, excluding any inner element, so no text should be shown because **that div has no text, only other elements**